# Android ConstraintLayout @dimens replaced with hardcoded values

Tags: android, dimensions, dimension, android-constraintlayout

**Heyho mates,**

currently I am learning the **new layout editor** of Android Studio with the new **ConstraintLayout**.

*By the way, I hate it.*

But I got the issue, that if I want to specify a **layout_height** with **@dimen**, it gets **replaced** with a **dp** value instead.

Someone else got this issue?

**Android Studio version 2.2.2 & 2.2.3 same issue.**

**Newest gradle version.**

Thanks in advance guys!

Edit :

Code example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageViewHeight"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/accept"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Also happens outside scrollview.**

Comment: post xml code here

Comment: You don't really need explicit code lines, it happens anywhere..

Comment: click on dp value of attribute. And check the dimen.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean... i tried but nothing happend for me.
Posted a code snippet now..

Comment: see this line `<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imageViewHeight"` Showing @dimen

Comment: Yes, but it gets replaced after some seconds by a hardcoded dp value

Comment: Its not replacing. Android Studio showing value of that dimen as per preview of the phone.

Comment: Honestly, it gets replaced. I know what you mean, but it is really replacing the dimen value..

Answer (score 1):

[Turns out this is a bug and will be fixed in Android Studio 2.3.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222019)

---

<strike>I think the reason behind this is, that ConstraintLayout as a WYSIWYG layout is inevitably meant to be edited/manipulated in the visual editor only.</strike>

Therefore keeping references to dimens in your dimens.xml would mean that as soon as you change something, move some elements around, these would not be relevant anymore and are hence replaced with "actual current values".

Also as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#adjust-the-view-margins):

> All margins offered by the tool are factors of 8dp to help your views align to Material Design's 8dp square grid recommendations.